# Django file uploads becoming corrupted when saved to the server

Tags: python-3.x, django

I'm using Django for a web application and I'm having issues with file uploads becoming corrupted when saved to the server. The files are uploaded from the Django admin site, and I'm using a FileField to save them to the server.

The issue is that the uploaded files become corrupted after they are saved to the server. When I try to open the files, I get an error message saying that the file is damaged or corrupted. I've tried uploading files of different sizes and types, but the issue persists.

Here is my model that contains FileField

```
 class Paper(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    source_file = models.FileField()
```

I've checked my server settings and everything seems to be configured properly. I've also checked the server logs, but there are no error messages or warnings related to file uploads.

I'm not sure what could be causing this issue. Has anyone else experienced this issue with Django file uploads? Is there a known solution to this issue?

Comment: Post your views.py and also you didn't specify a path for the file upload field in models. It should look something like this `source_file = models.FileField(upload_to="files" )`. And also have you configured your media url

Comment: The file does get uploaded to media folder automatically, as I have configured static files

Comment: OK, what of views.py